# Cannot set mask for input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code:

```
    <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="0000 - 0000 - 0000"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + ' - ';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{4}\/\d{4}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + ' - ';
        }"
>
```

The input looks like this: [image] . When I type numbers like 463985637851, the text on my input should be "4639 - 8563 - 7851".

By the way I am not getting the separation between numbers. What is wrong here?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJT75/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMAZA/)

Give input field an id:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0000 - 0000 - 0000" id="mynum" />
```

JS:

```
$('#mynum').keyup(function() {
  var v= $(this).val().split("-").join(""); 
  if (v.length > 0) {
         v= v.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
   }
  $(this).val(v);
});
```

Comment: Use `maxlength="14"` - 12 number and 2 hyphen's. Then, use regex to validate it.